# WPF + Showing ouput of bat file in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, process

I am trying to execute a bat file through my WPF application on a button click.
I want the output of the batch file to be displayed in a TextBlock(with vertical scroll) of WPF application.

I am able to execute a bat file using Process.Start

Here is my Code

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\bin\run.bat";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-X";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

How to proceed further?
Thanks

Comment: You need to use `Process.RedirectStandardOutput`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I will flesh out my comment with an answer. You need to redirect the output of your bat file, you do that by using [`Process.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Taking your code and the MSDN Library page's code will give you something like this.

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\bin\run.bat";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-X";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //Changed Line
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;  //Changed Line
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //Changed Line
process.WaitForExit(); //Moved Line
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to redirect standard output to your text file using the gtr symbol ">". e.g

command>myfile.extension

and the opposite executes the commands in a file one line at a time e.g

command